# ASP.NET host issues with SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

NET 4.0 application along with it's SQL Server 2008 database to an online host. The ORM layer is Entity Framework. However, the application does not read from a table in the database - in short it does not see the database and it shows network instance error bla bla bla... whenever a query is made against it.

I checked if there was data in it and it returned the data in one of the tables i put it in. Anyone with a clue what might be wrong? Below is part of my web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated  Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="DemographicDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DemoGraph.csdl|res://*/DemoGraph.ssdl|res://*/DemoGraph.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DemographicDB.mssql.somee.com;initial catalog=DemographicDB;persist security info=False;user  id=west;pwd=westhouseit;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: it will be handy if you could also show us the network instance error bla bla bla... please

Comment: Try this command: "telnet DemographicDB.mssql.somee.com 1433". What do you get?

Comment: Hi Amiram, it connects and gives me a window with a blinking cursor. @HatSoft: This is the error:A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)...familiar eh?

Comment: I have tried pinging DemographicDB.mssql.somee.com to get the ip address to use instead of the DNS name, i have used 204.27.57.76, 1433 and all that did not work. Is there a part of the connection string that should change that has not been changed? I am wondering....